# Split comma separated string into several rows in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I want to achieve the output in 2nd table based on the input from the first table. I want to do this via a SSIS package.

[image]

So far I tried creating a package with bypassing error whenever there comes a comma (,), but that didn't work. Also tried using checkpoints, couldn't achieve it that way as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Just get a string splitting function like [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and you just need simple select statement

Comment: I think there are 2 methods in SSIS: using **SQL Command as OLEDB Source** or using a **Script Component**, check my answer for more details

Answer (score 4):

### 1st Method - You can achieve this using an SQL statement

In the Data Flow Task, in the `OLEDB Source` select the source type as `SQL Command` and use the following command *(replace `Tablename` with your table name)*:

```
;WITH tmp(ID,  DataItem, [Group]) AS(
SELECT ID, LEFT([Group], CHARINDEX(',', [Group] + ',') -1),
       STUFF([Group], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Group] + ','), '')
FROM [Tablename]

UNION ALL

SELECT ID,  LEFT([Group], CHARINDEX(',',[Group]+',')-1),
       STUFF([Group], 1, CHARINDEX(',',[Group]+','), '')
FROM tmp
WHERE [Group] > ''
)

SELECT ID,  DataItem
FROM tmp
ORDER BY ID
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51a99/2/0)

**References**

- [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

---

### 2nd Method - Using Script Component

You can refer to this link for a detailed answer:

- [Split multi value column into multiple records](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT
    tbl.id,
    Splita.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [Group]    
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE( [Group], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS Col1,
             id

      FROM  Table1
    ) AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY Col1.nodes('/X') AS Splita(a)
```

here is the [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/81c9a/4) link.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to split with TSQL on the source database, you can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) on SQL server 2016 and onwards.

Comment: The OP added *ssis-2012* tag which means that he is using sql server 2012